# overridePendingTransition with multiple views

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, translation

overridePendingTransition takes 2 animations and animates the entire screen.

How would i Transition between 2 activities animating 2 seperate views?

Basically i want to make a double door open when i press a button and see the next activity behind it while its opening.

i can easily do slide the screen to the next screen with this:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.transition_left_in, R.anim.transition_left_out);
```

and i can open the double door but without Transition like this:

```
public void loginOnClick(View view)
{
    final RelativeLayout leftPanel = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayoutLeft);
    final RelativeLayout rightPanel = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayoutRight);

    Animation animLeft = new TranslateAnimation(1, 0, 1, -1, 1, 0, 1, 0);
    animLeft.setDuration(1000);
    animLeft.setFillAfter(true);
    animLeft.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
    {
        @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
        {
        }

        @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
        {
            leftPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rightPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
        {
        }
    });
    Animation animRight = new TranslateAnimation(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0);
    animRight.setDuration(1000);
    animRight.setFillAfter(true);

    leftPanel.startAnimation(animLeft);
    rightPanel.startAnimation(animRight);
}
```

I know i can just change the activity after an animation, but i want to see the next activity while animating the previous one.

How would i do this?
any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

the best workaround i found is to use an `include` in the first activity xml to include the context of the second activity. (behind the doors that will open) But its not exactly what i want, as some things on the UI change after the `onCreate()` of the second method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest a workaround:

Disable default window animation for your theme by adding:

```
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
```

Now, just before Activity_2 has to start, Activity_1 has `double doors` in view. Instead of carrying out the animation in Activity_1, start it in Activity_2's `onCreate(Bundle)`.

You will need to place the `double doors` over Activity_2's layout. Place the contents of `loginOnClick(View view)` after the call to `setContentView(R.layout.activity_2)` in Activity_2's `onCreate(Bundle)`.

Because the `windowAnimationStyle` is set to `null`, the transition from Activity_1 to Activity_2 will appear to be seamless.

**Edit:** Tested this just now, and it works well.

Comment: I have also tried this but this means i have to place all my activity1 java code in activity2 and there is a lot of code. i would prefere 2 different activities. But it seems like its impossible. On the IOS version of the application this was simple to do.

Comment: @NicolasTyler Wait, why would you need to place all of Activity_1's code in Activity_2? At the point where you move to Activity_2, call `startActivity(Intent)`, leave the doors on screen, and start the animation in Activity_2. Before this point, its Activity_1. I can write up an example if you can provide more code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i got it working but i would like to see more alternatives before i accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an animation for the other activity so that it grows from the middle of the screen outwards horizontally towards the sides of the device at the same speed as the doors open. This would make the illusion of seeing the doors open up to the application.

Comment: I don't want it to grow. i want 2 translation animations.